# how to `new` objects with class defined dynamically at runtime?

Tags: class, generics, dynamic, typescript

I have a list of Plugin classes that I want to instantiate at runtime, but I'm getting the `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.` error.

This happens if I declare a base class for things to extend

```
class BaseAnimal { }

class Dog extends BaseAnimal {
    say() { return "dog says woof"; }
}

class Cat extends BaseAnimal {
    say() { return "cat says miaow"; }
}

// declaring BaseAnimal as the base type breaks things
// var AnimalClasses:BaseAnimal[] = [Cat, Dog];

// this is OK tho using :any
var AnimalClasses:any[] = [Cat, Dog];

AnimalClasses.map( (Klass) => {
    var animal = new Klass;
    debug( Klass, "says", animal.say()) ;
})
```

gives:

```
[Function: Cat] +0ms says cat says miaow
[Function: Dog] +3ms says dog says woof
```

But it seems unclean to just use :any as the type for these. 
Is there a way to use generics here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof BaseAnimal`:

```
class BaseAnimal {
    say(): string { throw new Error("Not implemented."); }
}

class Dog extends BaseAnimal {
    say() { return "dog says woof"; }
}

class Cat extends BaseAnimal {
    say() { return "cat says miaow"; }
}

var AnimalClasses: typeof BaseAnimal[] = [Cat, Dog];

AnimalClasses.map((Klass) => {
    var animal = new Klass;
    debug(Klass, "says", animal.say());
});
```

Since you are referring to types and not instances.

Comment: Curious, what is `typeof BaseAnimal` -- or can it not be written in any other way?

Comment: @luqui try doing `var baseAnimalType = BaseAnimal; var baseAnimalInstance = new BaseAnimal();`. You will see by hovering over the variable name that `baseAnimalType` is typed as `typeof BaseAnimal` and `baseAnimalInstance` is typed as `BaseAnimal` ([Example](http://goo.gl/VX8ycd))

Comment: so `typeof` gets parsed at runtime or compile time by typescript?

Comment: It is parsed at compile time. Because all the type information in your code can be statically determined.

Answer (score 1):

So when you define a class in typescript, you are introducing two things:

1. A named type that with all the instance properties in the class
2. A named value that refers to the constructor function with static properties

When the class name `Dog` is used as a type annotation like:

```
var dog: Dog;
```

The typescript compiler recognizes the `Dog` as an instance type. However when you used it as an object like:

```
var dog = Dog;
```

The `Dog` here is inferred as the constructor function instead of the type.

Therefore your `AnimalClasses` element of type `BaseAnimal` is not assignable to `Cat` or `Dog`, because they are both constructor functions.

Comment: good explanation, i think i get it thanks! but the other solution here shows a way to actually do it. do you think that's the best approach?

Comment: Sure. Just to add my 2 cents.